# Jquery AJAX Global Timeout (Entire Application) Im using $.get & $.post (can't use $.ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout, global

I have created the spring web application with jquery. For every ajax call im using $.get or $.post (NOT $.ajax).

But I didn't handle any ajax timeouts or ajax error. Now my application is deployed in the server, I can't make any major changes.

Pls help me how to handle the **AJAX Timeout for the entire web application** and i should **alert("Ajax Timeout")** globally. additionally whatever the ajax error, i should alert the error message to the user.

I heard about **$.ajaxSetup** and **$.ajaxError**
But How to use them in my web application, Do i need to add it in document.ready ??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can attach an [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler to *document*

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
         //Do whatever
    });
});
```

Edit: To set Ajax timeout globally, you have to use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 2000 //Time in milliseconds
});
```

**Note**:`$.ajaxSetup` should be set **before** other Ajax calls.

Comment: how to set the ajax timeout globally?

Comment: How to add alert message when request timeout?

Comment: I am using ajaxSetup but timeout not work for me. Not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
$.ajaxSetup({timeout: 100});

Answer (score -1):

Here is how to set-up the `ajaxError` in your application.

Do this **once** inside the document ready.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
});
```

The `xhr.status` is the http status code returned, the most common `404` (not found), `201` (created), `403` (forbidden), for a list of these status codes refer to: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html.

Comment: how to set the ajax timeout globally?